# Quotifiable Subcategories

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

I [asked this on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418512/quotifiable-subcategory) but haven't got a response. If this question is unsuitable for this website please let me know.

In Popescu's textbook *Abelian Categories with Applications to Rings and Modules*, Theorem $3.3$ of section $4.1$ says:

> Let $\mathscr A$ be a dense subcategory of a locally small abelian category $\mathscr C$ and let $\Sigma = \Sigma_{\mathscr A}$. Then the category $\mathscr C_\Sigma$ of additive fractions of $\mathscr C$ relative to $\Sigma$ exists.

Where $\Sigma_\mathscr A$ is the system of all morphisms $s$ of $\mathscr C$ such that $\ker s$ and $\text{coker } s$ are in $\mathscr A$.

Now, in the exercises for this section, there is a question that says:

> Let $\mathscr A$ be a dense subcategory of $\mathscr C$. Give sufficient conditions (more general than in Theorem $3.3$) for the existence of the category $\mathscr C/\mathscr A$. (In this case $\mathscr A$ is called a *quotifiable subcategory*). Then the category $\mathscr C/\mathscr A$ is abelian and the canonical functor $T : \mathscr C\rightarrow \mathscr C/\mathscr A$ is exact.

Elsewhere $\mathscr C/\mathscr A$ is defined to be $\mathscr C_{\Sigma_{\mathscr A}}$.

My question is about what he means by the more general than in Theorem $3.3$. I don't understand what is being asked here, and I can't find any references anywhere to a quotifiable subcategory. The google search "quotifiable subcategory" returns no results.

Can anyone shed any light on this? The reason I'm interested is due to another of the exercises here.

> Let $H : \mathscr C\rightarrow \mathscr C'$ be an exact functor. Let $\ker H$ be the full subcategory containing all $X\in\mathscr C$ such that $HX = 0$. Then $\ker H$ is a dense subcategory. Furthermore, let us assume that $\ker H$ is quotifiable. Then the functor $\bar{H} : \mathscr C/\ker H \rightarrow \mathscr C'$ induced by the universal property of the quotient category is faithful.

I paraphrased that slightly, but I'm interested in it because I would like to know sufficient and necessary conditions for that induced functor to be faithful, and if quotifiable is necessary I'd like to understand what it means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More than suitable for MO! This type of question is a perfect fit.

Comment: Is the notation $\mathcal{C}/\mathcal{A}$ defined anywhere?  Context suggests that it means $\mathcal{C}_{\Sigma_{\mathcal{A}}}$.  If this were the case, then Theorem 3.3 would give the condition "$\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}$" for the existence of $\mathcal{C}/\mathcal{A}$, and the exercise would be to give a more general condition.

Comment: Yes that is how $\mathcal C/\mathcal A$ is defined. Do you know of a more general condition? I've only ever seen the quotient of an abelian category defined for a dense subcategory.

Comment: By “$\mathscr A$ is quotifiable” Popescu means “$\mathscr C/\mathscr A$ exists”.

Comment: But if the quotient by a dense subcategory already exists, why further assume quotifiable? Surely quotifiable implies dense, and dense is already sufficient for the existence of the quotient, is it not?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that…

Comment: Did you try to solve the second exercise?  I did it very very sketchily and it didn’t seem that I needed a further condition.

Comment: Yeah I did and it didn't seem to me like a further condition was necessary either which just confused me even more. I suppose it's not worth losing too much sleep over but I am still curious as to what it means.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that the exercise is already assuming density.  The only other condition I can see in theorem 3.3 that isn't assumed in the exercise is that $\mathscr{C}$ is locally small.  Maybe the point is to interpret theorem 3.3 as saying "if $\mathscr{C}$ is locally small, then any dense subcategory of it is quotifiable" and the exercise is to find additional conditions on a dense subcategory that make it quotifiable even in the absence of local smallness?

Comment: (If you haven't already, you might want to check his definition of "locally small" --- nowadays category theorists universally use this to mean "the hom-sets are all small sets", but I think there is a different archaic meaning that has something to do with generation by a small subcategory instead.)

Comment: He defines a locally small category as one in which for every object $M$ the class of subobjects of $M$ is a small set (where subobjects are defined as isomorphism classes of objects with monomorphisms into $M$). This is necessary to define the homsets in the quotient, and is implied by the existence of a set of generators, so would the condition '$\mathscr C$ has a set of generators' be the condition I'm looking for?